# Customizing kernel and uname info

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, kernel, compiling

For practice I want ot build a custom kernel on my Ubuntu 16.04. I followed this guide:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

That went well, kernel builds and installs and boots fine. Now I want to add a
custom version string that can be seen with 'uname -a' or something.

The guide says

> In order to make your kernel "newer" than the stock Ubuntu kernel from
>   which you are based you should add a local version modifier. Add
>   something like "+test1" to the end of the first version number in the
>   debian.master/changelog file, before building. This will help identify
>   your kernel when running as it also appears in uname -a.

I am not sure what they mean. I have changed the first line of the changelog file from

```
linux (4.4.0-59.80) xenial; urgency=low
```

to

```
linux (4.4.0-59.80-mykernel1) xenial; urgency=low
```

That then gives me an error during building

```
dh_installchangelogs -plinux-headers-4.4.0-59.80-mykernel1
dh_installchangelogs: package linux-headers-4.4.0-59.80-mykernel1 is not in control info
dh_installdocs -plinux-headers-4.4.0-59.80-mykernel1
dh_installdocs: package linux-headers-4.4.0-59.80-mykernel1 is not in control info
dh_compress -plinux-headers-4.4.0-59.80-mykernel1
dh_fixperms -plinux-headers-4.4.0-59.80-mykernel1
dh_installdeb -plinux-headers-4.4.0-59.80-mykernel1
dh_installdeb: package linux-headers-4.4.0-59.80-mykernel1 is not in control info
```

Next thing I tried was to modify the root Makefile like so:

```
EXTRAVERSION = mykernel1
```

But that had no effect whatsoever.

Where am I wrong or what else can I try? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Local version modifiers should start with `+` char, like `+test1` in the docs. Adding `-mykernel1` that starts with `-` presumably makes it invalid.