# Packaging fails upon compiling 16.04 HWE kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling, packaging, makefile

**Short summary:**

Packaging script looks in wrong path.

**Detailed error summary:**

To compile the kernel, I used the compilation instructions from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel), which included the steps:

1. Checkout git sources from:

   ```
   git clone git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/xenial -b hwe
   ```
2. Modify the configs using:

   ```
   fakeroot debian/rules clean
   fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
   ```

   where I changed only one option, the equivalent to `CONFIG_DMA_CMA=y`, listed under *Device drivers* → *CMA*. As it is suggested, I added a custom name for the new kernel by setting it in menuconfig, which ultimately results in `CONFIG_LOCALVERSION="-cma"` in the config file.

   I changed it for the x64 and x64lowlatency configs (I also tried to change it for i386 and armhf, also, but this made no difference).
3. Build it with:

   ```
   CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=4 fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch
   ```

The output of the error is:

```
...[a seemingly succesful compile and lots of INSTALL]...
#
# Build module blacklists:
#  - blacklist all watchdog drivers (LP:1432837)
#
...[more output]...
ls: cannot access '/home/user/kernel/xenial/debian/linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic/lib/modules/4.15.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/watchdog/': No such file or directory
#
# Remove all modules not in the inclusion list.
#
...[more output]...
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /home/user/kernel/xenial/debian/linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic/lib/modules/4.15.0-65-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat '/home/user/kernel/xenial/debian/linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic/lib/modules/4.15.0-65-generic/kernel': No such file or directory
debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:89: recipe for target 'install-generic' failed
make: *** [install-generic] Error 1
```

The message from `ls` is indeed correct, as this claimed directory does not exist:

```
/home/user/kernel/xenial/debian/linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic/lib/modules/4.15.0-65-generic/kernel/drivers/watchdog/
```

Only this directory with the `-cma` addition exists:

```
/home/user/kernel/xenial/debian/linux-modules-4.15.0-65-generic/lib/modules/4.15.0-65-generic-cma/kernel/drivers/watchdog/
```

but it is not searched for.

I localized the output of *blacklist all watchdog drivers* to come from:

```
./xenial/debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk
```

But I fail in identifying the parts in the Makefile, which path variable is wrong and how I would fix it. This surpasses my Linux knowledge.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I did partially solve the problem.

The instructions contain a note that I must have overlooked and that contradicts instructions that describe to do it otherwise:

> NOTE: do not attempt to use CONFIG_LOCALVERSION as this *will* break
>   the build.

Now at least the abovementioned problem is solved. However, the build is not yet successful and fails at a later stage. I will open another question how to continue with custom kernel creation without having to build/compile everything from scratch over and over again.

However, in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871508/customizing-kernel-and-uname-info) the way following the instructions by the letter (edit the changelog file) did not work. I'm curious what I will find...